# What is purpose of Read Lock in java synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am new in multithreading and i am confused , why read lock is needed in java synchronization .Also i understand the use case of write lock.In which scenario we need to limit the reader access for threads.
Suppose we don't have read lock in java , then what's the problem.

Comment: If you take out a read lock, you prevent another thread taking out a write lock and altering stuff as you are reading it.

Comment: I've found [some info here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html), perhaps it might help.

Comment: Then what's the benefit of Read and Write Lock , if only one lock can acts at the same time.

Comment: Multiple readers don't block each other

Comment: Are you familiar with [Readers–writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem)?

Comment: what if you have a compound object. 1) you start reading it, 2) someone changes it, 3) you finish reading it. Afterwords you could end up with completely messed data

Comment: Have you considered reading the Javadoc?

Comment: Have you considered reading the Javadoc(2)?

Comment: You may meet the dirty read problem while thread writing concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is shared resource R. A thread T1 is reading it and it's not locked as there is no read lock in java(As you said)meanwhile a second thread try to access the R1 to write on it. As  there in no information attached to the  R1 that a thread is currently read it , Second thread will get the write lock and start writing  to it and is unexpected. Read lock is the extra information attached to resource that tell the later threads that resource already in access for reading , wait for write access or you can access only for read.
Read lock can be access by multiple thread.

From [Java 11 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html#readLock())

> The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads,
> so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.